# Sudden spike in billing/ account activity

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-billing

I was subscribed to the AWS free tier, and my bill was $52 after the exhaustion of the free tier quota in AWS sagemaker service by 1st week of March 2018. After this billing- I'm working on S3 and Lambda only(free tier use)

My bill was $52 by 29th night, On the 30th morning, we were shocked to say the least, that the bill has raised to around $250 after being idle for the night. We immediately decided to close
the account to avoid any further spike in the bill. By the time we
did all this the billing has crossed $800.

Below is the detail from Bill
[image]

There are 98,281,759 requests there is US East region, but my program hardly used 1000-10000 request, there is no way it uses this much requests that too in few hours of time.

What further action should we take? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: If this is not a right place then tell me which place is appropriate i'll move this post to that forum

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires us to divine what is in OP's bill from AWS.

Comment: Look at the information AWS provides in the billing console. We can't possibly know what you're being charged for, but it's clear that you're somehow using more resources than you realized.

Comment: Updated with bill detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact AWS Customer Service. They handle billing-related queries.

The usage might be related to SageMaker, or you might have opened public access to an S3 bucket. The [Cost and Usage Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html) would be able to provide more details.

Comment: i stopeed all sagemaker activites already so it wont be a cause, it might be public access to S3. Is there any other possibilities you can think? (Im new to cloud and AWS, so i cant think any)

Comment: The Cost and Usage Report will reveal all! (Although I'm not sure if you can see historical data before turning it on.)